# in ionic app, need to display map in the 3rd view there i am getting error "read property 'firstChild' of null"

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic application, I have created 4 views in templates folder in the 3rd one, i need google map,
There I gave map id and defined map api script in the index page but still I am facing issue like:- **read property 'firstChild' of null**

If I am adding the same map div in the index page inside `<body>` or `<ion-nav-bar>` it's working fine.

**Here is the div I have used in 3rd view:**

```
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
```

**my script in index page is :-**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJPP8ZXFrsqzaApDmQE09W7DTYP2oiABw"></script>
```

**my map function is in controller :- **

```
$scope.mapFn=function(){

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
            var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: "My Location"
            });
        });

        $scope.map = map;
    });         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I made working example for ionic map. In that example I am displaying google map in the HomeTabCtrl. Please check below link:

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/hirojaisinghani/pen/QKYVYV)

HTML

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places,geometry,drawing"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.3.2/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <style>
    .editable-image {
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;


}
    #map {
     height:200px;
     width:600px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

      <ion-tab title="Map" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-football" href="#/tab/about">
        <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-bag" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
        <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Home">
      <ion-content >
        <h2>Google Map</h2>
        <div id="map"></div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Facts">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
        <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
        <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
        <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
        <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
        <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
        <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
        <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
        <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
        <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/mylongform.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-modal-view class="product edit create">
          <form name="itemEdit" novalidate>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive fix-buttons">
              <a class="button" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</a>
              <h1 class="title">Form</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content has-bouncing="true">
              <div class="row" ng-class="{'no-padding-top': !data.editItem}">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="item item-input large">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Title">
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="editable-image horizontal-image">
                <div class="add"><i class="icon ion-upload"></i>
                  <div class="instructions">Tap to upload photo</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="item item-input large">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Price">
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row description-row">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="item item-input text">
                    <textarea placeholder="Description" rows="5" ng-model="item.description" ng-Required="true" name="description" lose-focus-on-return></textarea>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row charity-row">
                <div class="col col-10 vert-center">
                  <div class="charity large"></div>
                </div>
              </div>


            </ion-content>
          </form>
        </ion-modal-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="About">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
        <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
        <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
      <ion-content class="padding">

      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="Contact">
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item">
            @IonicFramework
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            @DriftyTeam
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

JS Code

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      cache: false,
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      },

    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/about");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {

    //$scope.$apply();
    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


$scope.initialise =  function() {



            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                mapOptions);


            //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
            var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
            var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: compiled[0]
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            $scope.map = map;

            console.log(map);

        };


        setTimeout(function () {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());
             $scope.$apply();
            }, 100);

        /* $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
            if (!$scope.map) {
                return;
            }

            $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                content: 'Getting current location...',
                showBackdrop: false
            });

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
                $scope.loading.hide();
            }, function(error) {
                alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
            });
        }; */

        $scope.clickTest = function() {
            alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
        };
});
```

Please check that and let me know if you face any issue in that.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Here as you mentioned **/tab/home** for map view, and this is the first view that will load first, It is working fine, but what i want like load map in another view that will load in 2nd or 3rd view like **/tab/about** . i.e, the view will load on click of some button.

Comment: **Here is my .config code :-**    `.config(function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider){
$stateProvider.state('firstPage',{
  url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/firstPage.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl'
}).state('home',{
  url: '/map',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'mapCtrl'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
})`           and i want to load map in  **templates/home.html** view

Comment: Here, I made some necessary changes in code according to your requirement. Now I am loading first about us view instead of home page.(map view.)
Please check that link  https://codepen.io/hirojaisinghani/pen/QKYVYV again and make necessary changes in your code. 
I hope now that will works.
Let me know if you still face issue in that.
Thanks

Comment: Hi **Hiro** thanks for your valuelab time, what you have gave me that works awesome in browser but in mobile i am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`  and   `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined(…)`  issues, Can you help me out of this problems

Comment: Hi **Kumar**  I checked that code in my iphone 6 that works fine. Which error you mentioned that most propabaly  occurs when google js not loaded. So please check your googleapis js link working or not. If you still face then please provide  your code link then I will check from my side.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks **Hiro** its working now, removed google API key from script and tried, working perfect in mobile also. Thanks alot..